# jQuery dialog doesn't work inside if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jQuery function followed by HTML code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submit').click( function() {
        var size = $('#file')[0].files[0].size;

        if(size > 100000) 
        {
            alert("Filesize is larger. Please try again.");
        }
  });

});

<div id="dialog" title="Message" style="display: none">
    <p>File size larger.</p>
</div>
```

If I replace the `alert()` with `$( "#dialog" ).dialog();` it doesn't work. However if the place the `$( "#dialog" ).dialog();` outside the `if()` it works. Is there any workaround for the problem I'm facing?

Any form of help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This `if(size > 100000)` should be `if(fsize > 100000)` - `fsize`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typing mistake while I copied it here.

Comment: Is your div dialog outside the script tag?

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/btL9C/4/ Check if your file is larger than the given size while testing

Comment: The alerts work fine inside if conditions. Your problem is somewhere else. Just debug your script and check if the 'if condintion', the 'size' variable and the jQuery selector are correct.

Comment: You will get the dialog only if you test with a file **larger than 1 GB**

Comment: may be form posting and thats the reason

Comment: Yes, I have a form that is posted on clicking submit. Is that an issue?

Comment: Give us jsfiddle where this doesn't work so we can check it.

Comment: @ShaunakD I think I made a blunder with the file size conversion into KB. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submit').click( function() {
var size = $('#file')[0].files[0].size;
if(size > 100000) 
        {
         document.getElementById("dialog").innerHTML = "Filesize is larger. Please try again.;"
        }
  });
});


<div id="dialog" title="Message"></div>
```

DEMO : `http://jsfiddle.net/8L2S4/`

Hopefully it works.

Comment: Thanks. This works but its not exactly what I wanted.